# $3^n+4^n<5^n$ for all $n>2$

Tags: induction

I'm doing the following induction proof and wanted to know if this was valid. I think it is, but I'm seeing more complicated solutions than what I did. What I did seems much easier.

Prove that $3^n+4^n<5^n$ for all $n>2$.

When $n=3$ we get $91<125$. No problem, now assume the result is true from $k<n$, $(5^k>3^k+4^k)$ and consider $5^{k+1}=5 \times 5^k>5(3^k+4^k)=5\times 3^k + 5\times 4^k>3\times 3^k+4\times 4^k=3^{k+1}+4^{k+1}$ since $5\times 3^k>3\times 3^k$ and $5\times 4^k> 4\times 4^k$.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: Yes, the proof is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Another proof, NO INDUCTION! -- just for fun.

Let $\ n\ge 3.\ $ then:

$$ 3^n + 4^n <\, 3^2\cdot 5^{n-2} + 4^2\cdot 5^{n-2}
 \,=\, (3^2+4^2)\cdot 5^{n-2}\, =\ 5^n $$

> 

REMARK   *If you look at the above proof under a magnifying glass then you may see induction after all -- just a trace.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method I like
for showing
$f(n) > g(n)$
for $n \ge n_0$.

1. Show that
   $f(n_0) > g(n_0)$.
2. Show that,
   if $n \ge n_0$
   and $f(n) > g(n)$ then
   $f(n+1)-f(n)
   \ge g(n+1)-g(n)
   $.

Then $f(n) > g(n)$
for $n \ge n-0$.

In this case,
$f(n) = 5^n,
g(n) = 3^n+4^n$.

Choose $n_0 = 3$.
$f(n_0) = 5^3=125,
g(n_0) = 3^3+4^3 = 91
\lt f(n_0)$.
So (1) holds.

If $n \ge 3$
and $f(n) > g(n)$ then

$f(n+1)-f(n)
=5^{n+1}-5^n
=4\cdot 5^n
\gt 4(3^n+4^n),\\
g(n+1)-g(n)
=2\cdot 3^n+3\cdot 4^n
\lt 3(3^n+4^n)
\lt f(n+1)-f(n)
$.